# How can I upload video, generate thumbnail and convert to different formats?

Tags: thumbnails

I haven't used WP in a very, very long time so please bear with me.

I'm using v3.3.1
I've used `get_children()` to display images of a page in a custom template.
I then customized a template to turn the images into a JQuery carousel.

Now, I want to add videos to that gallery.

**My question is**, how can I:

1. Have thumbnails generated once I upload videos via media library.
2. Convert the videos into multiple formats (all or most of: mp4, webm/vp8, ogg/vorbis & swf) so that I can use them with [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

I'd really appreciate some direction on this

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Answers:**

1. Try [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/video-embed-thumbnail-generator/) which uses the [ffmpeg library](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)
2. This [video conversion plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/aviberry-wordpress-video-conversion-plug-in/) looks quite promising with [wide range of format support](http://www.aviberry.com/supported_formats.html)

Hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Sisir, that will be useful for future projects. I'd vote you up but, apparently, I don't have enough reputation to do so.